# htaccess remove 2 sublinks from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Example:

Redirect

```
http://domain.com/portfolio/items/wearable-hydration-monitor
```

To

```
http://domain.com/wearable-hydration-monitor
```

The 2 subfolders will always be the same, /portfolio/items/

the variable would be wearable-hydration-monitor

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/portfolio/items/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It didn't work because the opening forward slash is not matched in a .htaccess file RewriteRule. Other than that it was right. You just needed to remove the forward slash after the caret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out :)

```
RedirectMatch 301 /portfolio/items/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1
```